# How do I make my program take 5 float values from a user and sort them in increasing order?

Tags: c++

What I exactly want my program to do is ask user to enter 5 values, output those 5 values to the screen, sort them from lowest to highest and output the sorted order to the screen.
I have the following code:

```
void sort(float[], int);

int main()
{

    const int SIZE = 5;
    float a[SIZE];

    cout << "Enter " << SIZE << "numbers:\n";

    for(int i = 0; i<SIZE; i++);
    cin >> a[i];
    sort(a,5);
    cout << "In sorted order: ";
}

void sort (float a[], int n)
{
    for (int i=1; i < n; i++)
        for (int j=0; j < n-i; j++)
            if (a[j] > a[j+1]) swap (a[j], a[j+1]);
}
```

Comment: Ok, and did this code work?

Comment: no it does not =( it terminates on void and does not output the sorted order

Comment: We're missing part of your code.

Comment: this is all that I could come up with....I don't know what else to do with it. this is exactly what I have  and tried to run

Comment: What about the closing } on the sort()

Comment: Where is `swap()`? Also, one reason it's not printing is because you haven't told it to.

Comment: I think you want `for (int j=0; j < i; j++)`.  Change n-i to i.

Comment: for(int i = 0; i<SIZE; i++);
    cin >> a[i]; will not work. I mean it will not take size values from cin. Get rid of the semicolon between the for and cin

Comment: I fixed the semicolon problem but how do I tell the program to print the sorted values? do I have to include void print (float[],int)?

Answer (score 3):

You have a semicolon after your `for` loop. Remove that and try again.

```
for(int i = 0; i<SIZE; i++)
    cin >> a[i];
```

Then call your sort function. Print out the array after you are done sorting.

```
sort(a,5);
cout << "In sorted order: ";
for(int i = 0; i<SIZE; i++)
        cout << a[i] << " ";
```

You can also take a peek at the working code [here](http://ideone.com/pMMxpi)